# Using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I want to send several strings from A to B using the DataInputStream.

I know how to send these across using `.write()` but I'm unsure of the best method to seperate the strings. In fact - after research, it doesn't seem as if it's possible unless I add a character in the string and split at B.

Any alternatives to using the `DataInputStream` would be considered. I was going to create a `Array` and send that across, although I wasn't sure how to do it.

So far I have:

```
public String getDetails() {       
 System.out.print("Name: ");
 String uiname = scan.next();
 pout.write(uiname);

 System.out.print("Address: ");
 String uiaddress = scan.next();

 pout.write(uiaddress);

 return "";
```

}

Comment: what's your problem with using `DataInput-/OutputStream`? If you're using it, you're sending binary data. No need to separate your strings as they're sent as single objects.

Comment: I have the streams working, but when I print the stream out at B, it joins all of the strings together. I was just wondering of a way around this. There must be a better method compared to how I have attempted it.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your strings are < 65536 characters long, you can use [DataOutputStream.writeUtf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) and [DataInputStream.readUTF()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF%28%29). If you needs something more complex than strings and primitives, you'll need to use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Example (which may contain syntax errors):

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(...);
out.writeUtf("foo");
out.writeUtf("bar");
out.close();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(...);
String s1 = in.readUtf();
String s2 = in.readUtf();
// that's all, folks!
```

The `writeUtf()` method preceeds the string with a count of its characters. The `readUtf()` method first gets the character count, then reads exactly that many characters. As long as you're just writing/reading strings, the streams can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

- Use `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` and  `DataInputStream.readUTF`
- Use a "holder" format like JSON (or XML) and build a JSON Array that you "print" then decode at the other end using any of the numerous libraires to do that (the JSON library at [json.org](http://json.org/java/) is sufficient for the task)

Comment: Why Object streams? DataInput/OutputStreams have those methods.

Comment: True. I was thinking writing Objects instances and did not realize it was available on the parent class